# Find the expectation and variance of X

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

A pdf is defined as
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
C(x+\frac{3}{2}),\quad0<x<2\\
0,\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

1. Find the value of C.
2. Find the expectation and variance of X.
3. Find the expectation of random variable $Z=\frac{X}{2X+3}$

What I tried:

1. Finding C is straightforward as we just need to make sure that $\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)dx=1$.
   \begin{align*}
                   1&=\int^2_0C(x+\frac{3}{2})dx\\
                   &=\left[\frac{C}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{2}Cx\right]^2_0\\
                   &=\left[\frac{C}{2}(2)^2+\frac{3}{2}C(2)\right]-0\\
                   &=5C\\
                   &C=\frac{1}{5}
               \end{align*}
2. Using $\mathbb{E}[X]=\int^\infty_{-\infty}xf(x)dx$,
   \begin{align*}
                   \mathbb{E}[X]&=\int^2_0x\left(\frac{1}{5}\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)dx\\
                   &=\left[\frac{1}{15}x^3+\frac{3}{20}x^2\right]^2_0\\
                   &=\left[\frac{1}{15}(2)^3+\frac{3}{20}(2)^2\right]^2_0-0\\
                   &=\frac{17}{15}
               \end{align*}
   Variance is $$\text{Var}[x]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2=\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)]-\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[x]^2$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)]=\int^2_0x(x-1)(\frac{x}{5}+\frac{3}{10})dx=\frac{7}{15}$$

Then, Var$[X]=\frac{7}{15}-\frac{17}{15}-(\frac{17}{15})^2=-\frac{439}{225}$

My concern is that the variance is negative, which should not be the case. Can I get some pointers on where I went wrong? Thank you.

3. This one is simple. I just need to find $\int^2_0\frac{x}{2x+3}f(x)dx$

Answer (score 4):

By linearity,
$$ \mathbb{E}[X(X-1)] = \mathbb{E}[X^2 - X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]. $$
Your additional term to compensate this should be $\mathbb{E}[X]$ rather than $-\mathbb{E}[X]$ (basically you turned $x^2$ in $x (x-1) -x$ instead of $x(x-1) + x$.

Comment: I should mention that to my professor. He gave us that formula in class and I just used it without checking to see if it was right. It makes a lot more sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

points 1 is ok

the expectation is ok

As variance is concerned

$$E[X^2]=\int_0^2 x^2f(x)dx=\frac{8}{5}$$

thus

$$V[X]=\frac{8}{5}-\left(\frac{17}{15}\right)^2=\frac{71}{225}$$

point 3, easy but incorrect

$$E[Z]=\int_0^2 \frac{x}{2x+3}f(x)dx$$

Comment: omg. I didn't even notice that I typed number 3 in so wrong. I had it handwritten correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your $C=1/5$ and $E(x)=17/15$ are correct, then $$E(x^2)=\frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{2} x^2(x+3/2)dx=\frac{8}{5}$$
$$Var=E(x^2)-(E(x))^2=\frac{8}{5}-(\frac{17}{15})^2=\frac{71}{225}.$$